# scipy.optimze curve_fit return wrong value

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I was trying to fit a specific function with scipy and I got weird results. I decided to test something I know the answer to so I created this:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit as cf
import numpy as np
import random

def func(x,a):
    return a+X

X =[]
for i in range (10):
    V = random.random()
    X.append(i+3 + V/10)

print cf(func, np.array(range(10)),np.array(X))
```

I expected to get something around 3, nevertheless, here the output:

```
(array([ -2.18158824e-12]), inf)
```

As a side note, I tried to see what I send something to `func` and I got this:

```
print func(np.array(range(10)),3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/py1759O-P", line 16, in <module>
    print func(np.array(range(10)),3)
  File "/tmp/py1759O-P", line 6, in func
    return a+X
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `x` and `X` as variable names when they carry such different meanings (or perhaps you didn't know Python is case sensitive?):

```
def func(x,a):
    return a+X

X =[]
```

`x` is a numpy array, `X` is a list, and `a` is a scalar parameter value.

`a+X` results in an error since you can not add a scalar to a list.

Answer (score 1):

In func, the argument is `x`, but `X` is used in the body of the function.

Here's a modified version of your code.  It uses a few more features of numpy (e.g. np.random.random() instead of random.random()).

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit as cf
import numpy as np


def func(x, a):
    return a + x


n = 10
xdata = np.arange(n)
ydata = func(xdata, 3) + np.random.random(n) / 10

print cf(func, xdata, ydata)
```

The output is

```
(array([ 3.04734293]), array([[  8.19208558e-05]]))
```